# Animation Best Practices

Tags: animation

I always struggle with getting the timing of everything perfectly for my final renders when animating. Playback as I model / animate hits around 12FPS, but when I render at 24FPS, everything is moving a lot faster than I anticipated. This often makes me need to reorganize all my keyframes and it's a total pain in the ass.

What is the best way to deal with this? I figured maybe I can render at a higher frame rate and just work on the timing in post-processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution for my issue was, and a very effective method for slowing down / speeding up the animations of multiple objects is to:

1.) Select the objects in question
2.) Navigate to the specified portion of the timeline
3.) Identify the keyframes and select them
4.) Press "S" to Scale and X to axis-lock to X axis
5.) Type in how much slower they should be spaced out (I typed 1.25 for 25% slower).

This helped me slow down areas of my scene that were going too fast without having to reposition all the keyframes.

Answer (score 8):

The animation workflow is:

1. make everything possible to lighten your viewport. Hide everything unecessary to see your animation, disable any rendering setting that's not relevant, lower subdivision modifiers, disable textures, son on...
2. You you still can't hit close to your final fps, then you need to do playblasts to preview your animation. Playblasts are [Viewport Render](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/viewport_render.html) in Blender, it's a fast render of your viewport as is, and it's a fast way to see your animation as it will be.

Playing with the scene framerate and scaling keys on the timeline is the best way to make errors down the line. And it's the wrong patch for a non-issue.

Answer (score 8):

There's really no single best practice; and the techniques used vary depending on the nature of the animation; but a lot can be accomplished by reducing scene complexity during animation testing, in order to get the test FPS close to the final FPS.

- Test in Solid mode, rather than Material Preview or Render
- Use the *Simplify* settings in the scene property to reduce the number of polygons in viewport mode
- Test with as few objects as makes sense, also to reduce the number of polygons
- Use a proxy object for testing whenever possible.  That's usually a very simplified version of the mesh.

The important thing is to nail as much of the animation as possible at nearly the final speed as possible before adding complexity.

Also, study the techniques used by manual animators.  Particularly pose-to-pose animation can be very good for character animation.

Comment: Is there any way to use something like time remapping? Or is there some type of plugin that could be ran to space out keyframes by a specified ratio to lengthen the animation?

Comment: You can scale the F-curves or use time remapping after the fact but neither of these things help you with getting the animation right in the first place, as far as I know.

Comment: I used the time remapping feature under Output, which seemingly achieved a good result. I know this won't work with every practical purpose but for this one style of animation it seems to have done alright (it's a car chase scene). I'm still pretty n00b re: F Curves and all that. Seems scary